# switch Container or View with different height within a scrollview

Tags: ios, view, height

I am trying to place different view with different heights within a scrollview by the click of a button. I draw a image of the problem:

[image]

If you click Button 1 (btn1) then we load view 1. If you click button 2 then we load view 2.

There are widgets above the buttons and below the displaying view. So The displaying view needs to have a dynamic height somehow that won't affect the other elements inside the scrollview. I tried container_views but cannot make then connect with viewcontrollers of different heights.

UPDATE: (here is another example)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "The displaying view needs to have a dynamic height somehow that won't affect the other elements inside the scrollview", if view 1 is lets say 200px and view 2 is 400px, should both views have same height or you just mean use views height and all widgets below the view follow as soon as your inserted view ends...

Comment: I want views with different heights. So if view1 = 200px and view2 = 400px. How can I display this in the box where I wrote "some container or view". Whatever is below this box should be automatically pushed down or up to adjust to the views different height.

Comment: Ill draw two examples then

Comment: @Ladislav How about now? Is it clearer?

Comment: Yes, it is clear now:) do you use autolayout?

Comment: @Ladislav Yes. I am using autolayout

Comment: So something like this: https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2I3X2x1B2v2k0L2f2X3U/Screen%20Recording%202018-04-26%20at%2002.10%20PM.mov Where dark gray view gets replaced buy red view and orange view gets pushed down and then red one is replaced with green one and orange is always just below the "container view"

Comment: @Ladislav Exactly that. If you answer I will implement and accept it :P

Comment: Ok, do you have your subviews to ScrollView added in a storyboard or Xib or in code?

Comment: they all added throught the storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve this problem, one of the `views` inside your `UIScrollView` is what I call a `containerView`, I have outlet to `containerView` inside my `ViewController` for example. Here is how my hierarchy is in the test app:

[image: Hierarchy]

As you can see I have a subview currently in the `containerView` and it has a height defined, the `BottomView` - in orange has a vertical spacing constraint defined to the `containerView`.

When user taps the replace view (`replaceView(_)` method in my example)  you just have to first remove all subviews from `containerView` and than add your new view, since we use auto layout the orange view will always be below the container view no matter how big/small the container view is...

```
@IBAction func replaceView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //remove all subviews from container view to be replaced
    for subview in containerView.subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let greenView = UIView()
    greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(greenView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
        greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
        greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
        greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
        greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])

    greenView.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

If you have a view you want to add in another Storyboard View Controller you can add it like so:

I am assuming your `Storyboard` is called `Main` and the Storyboard ID for the view controller I am adding is `GreenStoryboardID`

```
    @IBAction func replaceView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //remove all subviews from container view to be replaced
    for subview in containerView.subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    let greenViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GreenStoryboardID")
    guard let greenView = greenViewController.view else { fatalError() }
    //add view properly so it is uses UIViewController contaniment methods
    addChildViewController(greenViewController)
    containerView.addSubview(greenView)
    greenViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
        greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
        greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
        greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
        greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
}
```

It will be up to you how you correctly size the view controller, here I am just setting its height to 50, but you could have a method in your `UIViewController` subclass for instance that has ability to let you know how big the view has to be to fit everything into the container view

Comment: So I can't do it using the storyboard then? I have complex stuff going on into the views which I have to switch between then. Can't do them grammatically. Unless I could switch between .xib files, that could work too!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by you can't do it using storyboard, if each of your views is its own view controller in the storyboard you can do it...\

Comment: So if I put the the view into a view controller, how you gonna put a view controller inside a container view? They all have different heights.

Comment: Updated the answer with how you can get a view from another Storyboard View Controller and using UIViewController containment to add it to container view

Comment: I have implemented your storyboard version. The only problem is that the view height does not work. It keeps the same height even though I set the height in the constraints. But it is swapping the views fine.

Comment: Then you probably have containerView height defined as a constraint.

Comment: However, if I dont set a height to the containerView I get erros in the storyboard

Comment: Then create an outlet to the height constraint and then deactivate it when you add subview to the containerview

Comment: Okay, I got it working now. I created the outlet and set the height of the container.constant = heightAnchor. Can't thank you enough for your help, really appreciated :P

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: would you know how to make the same using autolayout so the view would adjust height dynamically without having to hardcode the  view height?

Comment: Not sure how you would do it with Storyboard, I am sure it can be done but I would have to think about it, if you have a view that you add manually with proper constraints it would just work automatically without the need of height constraint, since container view subview would dictate its parents view

Comment: Problem is that you can't have a container_view without a fixed height in the storyboard even if you add subviews programatically you would have to adjust the height anyway.

Comment: If you have one subview that holds all other views you count use it as bottom constrain ancor and it might just work...

Comment: I got it working by summing the heights of all inner views and then setting the heightarchor of the view and the containerview height :P